# Cocoon How to Get Inserted Item ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, materialize, cocoon-gem

I'm using the Cocoon gem with Rails to handle my nested forms. I'm also using materialize.css. When I dynamically add a select field materialize does not automatically initialize it. I need to do it initialize it in my jQuery code with `$('select').material_select();` The problem is that cocoon appends and id to each item. Is there a way I can get that id in a cocoon `cocoon:after-insert` callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the callback you get the inserted piece of html, so you could do something like

```
$('form').on('cocoon:after-insert', function(e, added_thing) {
  added_thing.find('select').material_select();
});
```

More examples can be found in the [documentation](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon#callbacks-upon-insert-and-remove-of-items).

Comment: That is much cleaner that what I came up with:
`$('.material-select').material_select('destroy');`
`$('.material-select').material_select();`